# Python OpenCV cv2.putText() - how to label multiple shapes with variate text?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm having an issue labeling my shapres with text. The image pixels and the values of the texts are all from a csv file. I tried the following and I'm getting the wrong output. The circles are correct but the text is wrong! As if I'm reading/printing all the string at each coordinate (which is circle).

```
dfa = pd.read_csv("filter.csv")
image = cv2.imread("image.png")
dfx = dfa[dfa['Timestamp'] == 1202000000]
dfx['Error_Bool'] = dfx['Percentage_Error']>=50
dfx['Error'] = dfx['Percentage_Error'].astype('int32')
text = dfx['Error'].to_numpy()
dfx = dfx[dfx['Error_Bool'] == False]
dfx = dfx[['Project_image_X', 'Project_image_Y']]
arr_2 = dfx.to_numpy()
for item_2 in arr_2:
    image = cv2.circle(image, (item_2[0], item_2[1]), 20, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    image = cv2.putText(image, "{}".format(text), (item_2[0], item_2[1]), 
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow('test image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: The Output]

Comment: look at your `text` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with dfx['Percentage_Error'] = str(dfx['Percentage_Error']). It seemed to convert the entire Percentage Error column into a string and then store that same string in every row of dfx['Percentage_Error'].